# Kubernetes high port needed on ingress

Tags: kubernetes, port

I have a Kubernetes cluster with an Ingress controller deployed. All external apps are hitting pods via this controller using their URI names and  port 443.

I have a client with an external app that needs to talk to a relay app inside of our cluster on a defined port (can't use 443). I would just expose the service the app is in using NodePort, but the required port is well outside of Kubernetes range (52311). I've done some googling and have seen that it's technically possible to increases this range but I don't want to do this and I haven't been able to bring up the apiserver component of the cluster when I make this change.

Anybody with greater experience of Kubernetes have an idea on how this could be done? Thanks

Comment: FYI: if you edit manifest apiserver at the server - use nano (do not use vim).

Comment: `I don't want to do this` - not exactly clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks both. I don't want to create a really high NodePort range as -from my understanding - it would mean all ports between 32767 and 52311 would be unusable by any other app on the host. I'd rather not go down that route.

Comment: Hi, I understand that you want to create NodePort for your application with port 52311 which is out side of k8s NodePort range. Can you paste error messages that you got while bringing up api-server? Also which documentation you followed?

Comment: If you don't want to increase kubernetes available ports range for NodePort services, your next option would be NATing rules 52311->k8s:31000